# Is is possible to lift an equivariant map of Loop lie algebras to an equivariant map of Loop groups?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, kac-moody-algebras

For brevity, let $LG=\mathbb{T}\ltimes \tilde{L}G$, the affine loop group and let $G$ be a simple simply conneceted Lie group. I have a map $\phi:L\mathfrak{g} \to L\mathfrak{g}$ that is equivariant. Is it possible to lift this map to an equivariant map on the level of groups? How is it done?

Comment: Do you mean to ask whether $\phi$ is the differential at the identity of a morphism $LG\rightarrow LG$?

Comment: Could you explain better what is $\tilde{L}G$, what is $\mathbb{T}$ and what is the action? "affine loop group" only yields 9 Google occurrences. also, $\phi$ is equivariant for which group action(s)?

Comment: Presumably, $\mathbb{T}$ is the energy circle, and $\tilde{L}G$ is the central extension of the loop group by the level circle.  I'm going to guess $\phi$ is a Lie algebra homomorphism.  I think $LG$ is usually used to denote the non-affine loop group, so the notation is a bit confusing.  When you say "equivariant", do you refer to the adjoint action?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use theorem 40.3 of

- Andreas Kriegl, Peter W. Michor: The Convenient Setting of Global Analysis. Mathematical Surveys and Monographs, Volume: 53, American Mathematical Society, Providence, 1997.[(pdf)](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/apbookh-ams.pdf)

You will have to handle some fundamental group obstructions. Equivariance (with respect to rotations of the parameter, I guess, or even with respect to the whole reparameterization group $Diff(S^1)$) is preserved.

Comment: This book looks like something I needed a year ago. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any reference that shows that the smooth loop group is regular? - nm, found it